# pure css vertical menu with submenu

Tags: html, css, menu

I did my research and was able to replicate what I'm looking for, well kind of--I just need help with a more specific vertical, pure CSS, menu.

I want my sub-menu popup to appear 10px to the left of the a not the `li`  attribute like most example found on the internet. I'm also looking for the most simple, pure CSS, type of menu--Nothing fancy.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="top-level">
        <li><a href="#">This is a long text</a>
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact me here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a>
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

my css:

```
#nav {border:1px solid cyan;}
    /* top level menu */
    #nav ul.top-level {border:1px solid red;}
    #nav ul.top-level li {position:relative;}

    /* sub level menu */
    #nav ul.sub-level {border:1px solid yellow;}
    #nav ul.sub-level {display:none;} /* hide */

    /* hover the sub menu*/
    #nav ul.top-level li:hover .sub-level {display: block; position:absolute; top:5px;}
```

How do I make it so the sub level menu pops up when I hover the `a` HTML anchor, not the `li`, and 10px to the left of the clicked `a` anchor?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that with pure CSS, you will have to use JS for that. It will be possible with CSS4 though... Which is a long way away. There is nothing wrong with opening the menu when hovering the li, you can make the anchor be the exact height / width of the li and there won't be much of a difference.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one and I think it will help

HTML

```
    <div id="nav">
    <ul class="top-level">
        <li><a href="#">This is a long text</a>
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact me here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a>
           <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

​

CSS

```
#nav {font-size:0.75em; width:150px;}
#nav ul {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#nav li {list-style: none;} 

ul.top-level {background:#FFFFFF;}
ul.top-level li {
 border: #FF0000 solid; 
 border-width: 1px;
}
 #nav ul.sub-level {border:1px solid yellow;}
#nav a {
 color: #000000;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:block;
 height:25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-indent: 10px;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:100%;
}
#nav a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav li:hover {
 background: #f90;
 position: relative;
}
ul.sub-level {
    display: none;  
}
li:hover .sub-level {
    background: #999;
    border: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    top: 5px;
}
ul.sub-level li {
    border: none;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}

#nav .sub-level {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```