# CSS3: nested lists as columns

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists

I have HTML which looks something like this:

```
<nav class="subnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Level 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Level 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Level 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Level 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Level 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm basically looking for a simple way to style it in CSS3 so that each sub-level shown as a separate column to the right (instead of being inserted and indented); something like this:

```
Level 1    |    Level2    >    Level3
Level 1    |    Level2    |    Level3
Level 1    >    Level2    |    Level3
Level 1    |              |
Level 1    |              |
```

Ideally, those columns should also have the following properties:

- flexible width, so other content can be  next to this; it should be aligned/floated left
- any level of nesting, and any number of entries in each level
- a common wrapper which expands with new levels an can be styled separately
- each column should take 100% of the wrapper's height

Am I asking for too much? :-)

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477184/pure-css-vertical-menu-with-submenu

Comment: Have you looked at [Son of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/vertical.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but no -- I think I wasn't quite clear. the thing is that I don't need the menus to pop open on hover or anything dynamic like that; I need them to be static, just showing submenus in columns while keeping the overall container (`<nav>` in this case) dynamic. I'll modify the question accordingly.