# hide and show sidemenu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this button when clicked the menus will be shown on right side of the screen. This menus have sub-menus or what we can call children then children has also a submenus on them. The problem is when I clicked the children of the main menu, the children menu will be gone. Then click some other menu when you click back to the previous menu the submenu of the children of the main menu is open

here is the jquery

```
$('.btn-menu-toggle').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on');   
    if($(this).siblings('.t-menus').is(':visible')){
        $(this).siblings('.t-menus').hide();
    }else{
        $(this).siblings('.t-menus').show();
    } 
});

$('ul.toggle > li > ul').hide();
$('ul.toggle > li:first-child > ul').show();
$('.t-menus li > a').click(function(){
   $('ul.toggle > li > ul').hide();
   $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nixiechen/ay19grLw/3/)
for visualization. What could be the problem?

Comment: C'mon nixie, I bet even you will understand that your CSS is way more complicated than is good for any coder. With a simple google search there are plenty demos to find of a simple 'vertical menu with submenu'. Here is an example [Create a vertical menu in CSS3 and HTML](http://www.thecodingguys.net/blog/css3-create-a-vertical-menu-with-sub-menu). You really need to redesign your code!

Comment: Even here on SO I found an [oldie from 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477184/pure-css-vertical-menu-with-submenu) to get you started. Check the code in the answer, work just fine. And another example from 2009 [Pure CSS Vertical Menu](http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-vertical-menu/) by Devin .R. Olsen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but I will try to help.

I think these the culprit is the second line on the code below.

```
$('.t-menus li > a').click(function(){
    $('ul.toggle > li > ul').hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});
```

When the main menu or sub-menu is clicked (on the first line), it will order all of sub-menu to be hidden first then order the next element to be displayed. It works well for the main menu because their sub-menu is located in different place.

[image]

The issue occur when you click on the sub menu because the sub-sub menu is located inside the sub-menu and the second line of code order all of the sub-menu to be hidden. So even if the code order the the next element of the sub-menu (which is the sub-sub-menu) to be displayed, it is still hidden because its parent (the sub-menu) is hidden.

[image]

Hope this can help.
Cheers!

Comment: but how can that be so that the sub-menu will not be gone when I clicked on it?